# Google Map V2 GIcon.shadow Image display in local development server but not from test server

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have custom marker icon (gif/png) to display on Google Map V2. I am using GICON and shadow property to set image path. The marker icons are diplaying as expected in development system. But after i deploy the system into server (Windows server 2008 r2, IIS 7.5), the icons are not displaying in some PC (not all). For some users the icons are displaying but for some users it is not displaying. I really appreciate all your help on this regard.

The code used is below :

```
var cm_baseIcon = new GIcon();

if (Records[i].Act == '1')  

   cm_baseIcon.shadow = "images/img/Markers/green.gif";

else

cm_baseIcon.shadow = "images/img/Markers/red.gif";

cm_baseIcon.iconSize = new GSize(27, 27);

cm_baseIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(9, 34);

cm_baseIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(0, 0);

cm_baseIcon.infoShadowAnchor = new GPoint(13, 27);

var markerOpts = {};

var icon = new GIcon(cm_baseIcon);

markerOpts.icon = icon;
```

Comment: Are you really developing new code in the deprecated [Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference)?

Comment: This development was started before V3 was released, so, we are in converting the application to V3 but still some of our applications are using V2

Comment: Yikes!  That's going to completely stop working in about 4 weeks time

Answer (score 0):

When I load your test page, I don't see any markers. Should the page create some markers when first loaded like this, or do I need to interact with the page in some way to get it to display any markers?

I set a breakpoint inside the `initialize()` function. Your `Records` variable is an empty array, i.e. `[]`. So the `for` loop in this function that creates the markers never executes.

Do you know how to use the JavaScript debugger in a browser? It will let you figure out what is going wrong without having to ask anyone. I and other people here are happy to help, of course, but you'll make *much* faster progress if you can debug this on your own.

I recommend the developer tools in the Chrome browser. Here is a [good introduction to the Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/). Read through that and try out the JavaScript debugger in particular. You can stop your code and look at variables, change values, single step through the code to see what each line does, etc. This will at least double your productivity in JavaScript, and probably even more than that.